# Regex not splitting text the same way

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, scrapy

I have a spider with scrapy and I am using a regex to split text on every word. It works in English and Korean, but when I try to scrape Spanish it doesn't break things up the same.

```
foo = 'the quick brown fox'
english = foo.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//p').xpath('string(.)').re(ur'[a-zA-Z\'-]+')
english = ['the','quick','brown','fox',]

foo = '빨른 깨를 있어요'
korean = foo.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//p').xpath('string(.)').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+')
korean = ['빨른','깨를','있어요']

foo = 'el zorro marron rapido'
spanish = foo.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//p').xpath('string(.)').re(ur'[\u0000-\u00FF]+')
spanish = ['el zorro marron rapido']
```

I just can't see why this would be treated any differently than the other languages.

Comment: I think Korean text should be: `빠른 갈색 여우` ;)

Comment: haha ok thanks. I was just typing quick and my Korean is not that great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other regular expressions, `[\u0000-\u00FF]` include space character (`\u0020`).

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(ur'[a-zA-Z\'-]', ' ')  # does not match space
>>> re.search(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]', ' ')  # does not match space
>>> re.search(ur'[\u0000-\u00FF]', ' ')  # match space
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe024fc4648>
```

Adjust the regular expression to exclude the space character. For example: `[\u0000-\u001f\u0021-\u00FF]+`

---

But, using regular expression here is not necessary. Simply using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is enough to get words splitted by spaces:

```
>>> 'the quick brown fox'.split()
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']
>>> '빨른 깨를 있어요'.split()
['빨른', '깨를', '있어요']
>>> 'el zorro marron rapido'.split()
['el', 'zorro', 'marron', 'rapido']
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but for my real purpose, .split() will not work.

Answer (score 3):

There are a good number of Unicode whitespace definitions both above and below your `\u00FF` boundary. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) for example. Can't you use `\w+` ? It would be the much preferred approach.